# Gridview Cells Loses Border After Grouping and Merging Cells in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in which I have merged three Columns based on similar datas... Grouping and Merging Cells are working fine. But certain cells of my GridView are losing border lines and it looks ugly to see... I want to know what is the reason for my Gridview cells to loose the borders...!

[image: Vertical Lines are missing for GridView Cells]

I want to show my GridView with proper border settings..
Please help me..

My MarkUp Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="4"
              Width="100%" Height="300px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-CssClass="fixedheadertable1">
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="District_Name" HeaderText="District Name">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Taluk_Name" HeaderText="Taluk Name">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Bank_Name" HeaderText="Bank Name">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Beneficiaries" HeaderText="Total Beneficiaries">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Active_Beneficiaries" HeaderText="Active Beneficiaries">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Suspended_Beneficiaries" HeaderText="Suspended Beneficiaries">
    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrolled_Active_Beneficiaries" HeaderText="Enrolled Active Beneficiaries">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrolled_Suspended_Beneficiaries" HeaderText="Enrolled Suspended Beneficiaries">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Approved_By_Tahsildar_For_Enrollment" HeaderText="Approved By Tahsildar For Enrollment">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Downloaded_By_Enrolment_Agency" HeaderText="Downloaded By Enrolment Agency">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Enrolled_For_Tahsildar_Approval" HeaderText="Enrolled For Tahsildar Approval">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Qualified_By_Tahsildar" HeaderText="Qualified By Tahsildar">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Downloaded_Yet_To_Open_Account" HeaderText="Downloaded & Yet To Open Account">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Uploaded_With_Account_Details" HeaderText="Uploaded With Account Details">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
  </asp:BoundField>
 </Columns>
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#DFFFDF" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Only Css Used is:

```
    .portletSmall .portletContent table {
    width: 975px;
}

    .portletSmall .portletContent table th {
    background-color:#DFFFDF;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

    .portletSmall .portletContent table td {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

    .portletSmall .portletContent table td img {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

    .portletSmall .portletContent table .alternateRow {
    background-color: #EEEEF9;
}

    .portletSmall .portletContentScroll {
    width: 313px;
    overflow:scroll;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
    .portletSmall .portletContentScrol2 {
    height: 380px;
    overflow:auto;

    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

    .portletSmall .portletContentScroll table {
    width: 213px;
}

    .porletSmallRow .portletLeft {
    float: left;
}

    .porletSmallRow .portletRight {
    float: right;
}

    .portletSmall .leftCorner {
    background-image:url(../images/GreenLTcnr.gif);
    width: 8px;
    height: 15px;
}

    .portletSmall .rightCorner {
    background-image:url(../images/GreenRTcnr.gif);
    width:8px;
    height: 15px;
}

.fixedheadertable1
{
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: can you share your aspx markup please?

Comment: I have added my markup code.. plz have a look @SoftSan

Comment: Thanks. also can you please share the css (I mean css class for beautification)

Comment: I have added my css.. pls have a look @SoftSan

Comment: actually I was looking for : HeaderStyle-CssClass="fixedheadertable1"> this class, but it's not there in ur css.  also can you set BorderStyle="Solid"? and see if it can helps you.

Comment: I posted the CSS snippet u asked, have a look @SoftSan

Comment: From your css, nothing looks like a problem... Except for these two images... `GreenLTcnr.gif` and `GreenRTcnr.gif`. Can you make sure these are not affecting the border somehow...

Comment: Simply right click on the cell you want to check and click inspect element (chrome)...

Comment: Can you get the HTML that is output and the CSS and put it in a jsfidle or similar?

Comment: I have removed all my css codes... then also it is not working

Comment: GreenRTcnr.gif and GreenLTcnr.gif is not making any problem.. And also I removed that as well @NaveedButt

Comment: I have added my codings in jsfiddle.. Here's the link...
http://jsfiddle.net/manikandan127/9pwro8zj/

Comment: Its working fine in chrome and FireFox but it is not working in IE..
pls help @JonP

Comment: which version of IE you're testing?

Comment: IE 11.. I have added my website in compatibility settings.. Thats why it is giving problem.. If i remove that, it is working fine..